# Junit testing for exceptions in a constructor?

Tags: java, exception, junit

In the following test I am trying to test if an exception has been thrown by the constructor when it is passed illegal arguments when trying to create the object, I have added validation in the setters of each instance variable that when they are passed invalid data they throw an exception.

```
// test for invalid const
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testInvalidBookStringStringStringInt() {

        // create a new book
        Book b = new Book(invalidISBN, invalidAuthor, invalidTitle,
                invalidRating1);

    }
```

The test is currently failing at the minute, what am i doing wrong?

Book class:

```
package practice;

/**
 * Class that creates a Book
 * 
 * @author Ross Young
 * 
 */
public class Book {

    // declaring instance variables
    /**
     * Book's ISBN
     */
    private String ISBN;

    /**
     * Book's Author
     */
    private String author;

    /**
     * Book's Title
     */
    private String title;

    /**
     * Book's rating
     */
    private int rating;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public Book() {

    }

    /**
     * Constructor with Args
     * 
     * @param ISBN
     * @param author
     * @param title
     * @param rating
     */
    public Book(String ISBN, String author, String title, int rating) {
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.rating = rating;

    }

    /**
     * Gets ISBN
     * 
     * @return ISBN
     */
    public String getISBN() {
        return ISBN;
    }

    /**
     * Sets ISBN
     * 
     * @param iSBN
     */
    public void setISBN(String iSBN) {

        if((iSBN.length()!=9)||(iSBN.length()!=12)){

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ISBN length");

        }else{

                this.ISBN=iSBN;
            }

        }


    /**
     * Gets Author
     * 
     * @return author
     */
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    /**
     * Sets author
     * 
     * @param author
     */
    public void setAuthor(String author) {

        if ((author.length() < 0) || (author.length() > 20)) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid author Length");
        } else {
            this.author = author;

        }
    }

    /**
     * gets title
     * 
     * @return title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * Sets title
     * 
     * @param title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {

        if ((title.length() < 0) || (title.length() > 20)) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid title Length");

        } else {

            this.title = title;

        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets rating
     * 
     * @return rating
     */
    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    /**
     * Sets rating
     * 
     * @param rating
     */
    public void setRating(int rating) {

        if((rating>5)|| (rating<1)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rating invalid");
        }
        this.rating = rating;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the `Book` class, including the constructor and all setters that attempt to validate the input.

Comment: just editing it to include it, cheers

Comment: Your tests are in the setters. The constructor has no checks at all. Where are you expecting you exception to be thrown?

Comment: this.ISBN = setISBN(ISBN)  in constructor???

Comment: If you want to avoid building illegal `Book`s, you should consider using the builder pattern; argument checking can be done there and you won't clutter your `Book` class

Comment: congrats! you created good test that found a bug in your code. see? it was worth it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `setX` methods from your constructor. Also change `setISBN` to :

```
if((iSBN.length()!=9) && (iSBN.length()!=12)) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ISBN length");
```

Answer (score 4):

Your constructor doesn't perform any of the checks that your setters check, so it won't ever throw any exceptions.  Setters aren't called when you directly assign an instance variable; they're only called explicitly.

Either have your constructor call your setters, or implement the validation in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks, so basically if im checking for validation throwing an expection, do this in the test method relating to the method in which the validation is. i.e. test the setter in this case?

Comment: I would test both the constructor and the setters; both of them should be capable of validating their inputs.

Comment: yeah, but how in this case would I test the constructor?

Comment: Have separate JUnit tests for each of your setters and a separate JUnit test for your constructor -- a total of 5 tests here.

Comment: thanks, but I am not testing for invalid args in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is setting the private variables and not using the public setters that contain the validation.

Comment: Sorry, im not sure what you mean?